# Footer not sticking to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

i have this CSS

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    padding:14px 0; 
    color:#eef1f6;
    border-top:4px solid #F36F25;
    bottom:0;
}
#footer-inner {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#footer span {
    color:#000000;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-inner">
        <span>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Integra Digital</span><br><br>
        <span>Dragon Enterprise Centre, 28 Stephenson Road, Leigh-on-Sea, Essex, SS9 5LY</span><br>
        <span>sales@integradigital.co.uk | tel: 01702 66 77 27 or Freephone: 08000 66 22 01</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

i need the footer to stay at the bottom of the page - not stick so its fixed when scrolling, just at the bottom so its not right underneath the content.

for example,

```
CONTENT

GOES 

HERE

FOOTER
```

not that, i need this:

```
CONTENT

GOES

HERE





FOOTER
```

hopefully im making sense?

Thanks

Comment: you want the footer to be at the bottom of the page and scroll with content?

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YVx3j/)?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   ...
}
```

to

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   ...
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: `i need the footer to stay at the bottom of the page - not stick so its fixed when scrolling, just at the bottom so its not right underneath the content.`. I think you didn't read the question properly or perhaps I'm reading it improperly.

Comment: waiting for anti-w3schools patrol :D

Comment: he didn't ask for fixed positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method I created in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/derek-duncan-snippets/4228927).  It pushes the footer to the bottom of the page even if there is not enough content to push it down there.

```
body, html { /*body and html have to be 100% to push header down */
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body > #wrapper { /* all content must be wrapped... #wrapper is my id.  Position relative IMPORTANT */
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
#content-wrap { /*#content-wrap is the wrapper for the content without header or footer | padding-bottom = footer height */
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
#footer { /* position must be absolute and bottom must be 0 */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**Edit**

To add whitespace above the footer, use this code:

```
#YourFooterID {
  ....
  margin-top: 5%; //or whatever value you would prefer
  ....
}
```

**Edit 2**

Here is a working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/CwKGD/

Comment: using absolute displays it at the top of the page

Comment: So would you like it to display under the content... but have alot of whitespace in between the footer and your content?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for 
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px 0;
  color: #eef1f6;
  border-top: 4px solid #F36F25;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#footer-inner {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#footer span {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-inner">
    <span>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Integra Digital</span><br><br>
    <span>Dragon Enterprise Centre, 28 Stephenson Road, Leigh-on-Sea, Essex, SS9 5LY</span><br>
    <span>sales@integradigital.co.uk | tel: 01702 66 77 27 or Freephone: 08000 66 22 01</span>
  </div>
</div>
```